# Unable to connect MYSQL database using JSP and TOMCAT

Tags: java, mysql, jsp, tomcat, jdbc

I am unable to connect database “test” created in mySQL using Java Server Pages (JSP) & Tomcat. I am getting the error message "Unable to connect to database".

I am using following software specifications

- Tomcat 6.0
- jdk1.6.0_21
- mySQL 5.1.49
- mysql-connector-java-5.1.13-bin

I have configured following environment variables as follow

- `CATALINA_HOME`: C:\Program Files\Tomcat 6.0
- `CLASSPATH`: C:\Program Files\Tomcat 6.0\lib\servlet-api.jar;C:\Program Files\Tomcat 6.0\lib\jsp-api.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_21\jre\lib\ext\mysql-connector-java-5.1.13-bin.jar.;
- `JAVA_HOME`: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_21

I have placed `mysql-connector-java-5.1.13-bin jar` file at following two locations:

- CATALINE_HOME\lib
- C:\Program Files\Tomcat 6.0\webapps\myapp\WEB-INF\lib

I am currently connected to mySQL Server 5.1 using default user name ‘root’ and ‘password ‘sohail’ Currently ‘test’ database is selected

I am running following code

```
<%@ page language="java" import="java.sql.*" errorPage=""%>
<%@ page import="java.util.*"%>
<html>
<head>
<title>Test DB Page</title>
</head>
<body>
<h3>Insert Data INTO MYSQL</h3>
<%
Connection con = null;
PreparedStatement stmt = null;
try 
{
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test", "root", "sohail");
stmt = con.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO login (loginID, firstname, lastname, gender, birthday, country, emailAddress) VALUES ('?','?','?','?','?','?','?')");
stmt.setString(1, request.getParameter("loginID"));
stmt.setString(2, request.getParameter("firstname"));
stmt.setString(3, request.getParameter("lastname"));
stmt.setString(4, request.getParameter("gender"));
stmt.setString(5, request.getParameter("Date of Birth"));
stmt.setString(6, request.getParameter("Country"));
stmt.setString(6, request.getParameter("emailAddress"));
int num = stmt.executeUpdate();
System.out.println(num + "records updated");
stmt.close();
con.close();
}
            catch (Exception ex) {
            out.println("Unable to connect to batabase.");
            }
 finally {
      try {
        if (stmt != null)
         stmt.close();
        }  
catch (SQLException e) {}
        try {
         if (con != null)
         con.close();
         } 
catch (SQLException e) {}
     }
%>
Done with new DB
</body>
</html>
```

Can anyone explain why I am not able to connect Database?

---

**Update:** I am getting following exception:

```
java.sql.SQLException: Parameter index out of range (1 > number of parameters, which is 0).
```

**Thanks you All**

**The Problem has been resolved by fixing following 2 errors.**

1- Dont Quote the parameters i.e. ?

2- Removed duplication i.e. Parameter no 6

Comment: What error message do you get?

Comment: Please change  out.println("Unable to connect to batabase.");
to print out the exception.
Edit your question to include the exception

Comment: instead of printing a simple message, print exception detail using ex.toString();

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> Parameter index out of range (1 > number of parameters, which is 0)
> ```

This means that `preparedStatement.setSomething(1, something)` has failed because `1` is larger than the available number of parameters which is `0`.

> con.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO login (loginID, firstname, lastname, gender, birthday, country, emailAddress) VALUES ('?','?','?','?','?','?','?')"

You should remove those singlequotes. You don't need to include them. The `PreparedStatement` will take care about the correct way of quoting. The placeholders `?` should be used unquoted. So:

> con.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO login (loginID, firstname, lastname, gender, birthday, country, emailAddress) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?)"

#### See also:

- [PreparedStatement tutorial](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html)

---

That said, this is not the recommended way to use JDBC nor JSP. Java code should be [avoided](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3177733/howto-avoid-java-code-in-jsp-files) in JSP. Also, the `CLASSPATH` environment variable is **ignored** by Tomcat.

Answer (score 1):

Don't quote the parameters. Use

```
INSERT INTO login (loginID, firstname, lastname, gender, birthday, country, 
    emailAddress)  VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");
```

Your code also set parameter no. 6 twice.

Comment: +1 for also noticing that position 6 is set twice. That may just be the cause of the error.

Comment: @extra: no, the exception message doesn't tell that. It would have errored the other way round.

Answer (score 0):

This code is hurting my eyes.

Scriptlet code like this is the wrong way to go.

If you must put this in a JSP, you ought to be using JSTL `<sql>` tags.

But even that's a bad idea.  You've got all your connection information in plain text in the page.  You aren't using a connection pool or JNDI lookup.  You say "test page" - don't let this go to production.